# unable to filter nested json object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to filter the below json data with `procedureName` & `hospitalName`  based on the user input in the GUI.

```
myObject= [
    {        
        "department": "Gynic",
        "treatmentList": [
            {
                "procedureName": "Bone Grafting",               
                "hospitalList": [
                    {
                        "hospitalName": "Renai",                        
                    },
                    {
                        "hospitalName": "Aster",                        
                    },
                    {
                        "hospitalName": "Appolo",                        
                    }
                ],                
            },
            {                
                "procedureName": "IVF",                
                "hospitalList": [
                    {
                        "hospitalName": "Renai",                        
                    }
                ],               
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For eg when the above json is filtered with procedure name 'Bone Grafting' & hospital name 'Renai' i should get the result in the below format.

```
     [
    {        
        "department": "Gynic",
        "treatmentList": [
            {
                "procedureName": "Bone Grafting",               
                "hospitalList": [
                    {
                        "hospitalName": "Renai",                        
                    },
                    {
                        "hospitalName": "Aster",                        
                    },
                    {
                        "hospitalName": "Appolo",                        
                    }
                ],                
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried with the below code.But it's not filtering the json

```
var x = myObject.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.treatmentList.some(function (item) {
        return item.procedureName == 'Bone Grafting';
    });
});
```

can some one help me to correct the mistake in my code?

Comment: It looks ok to me.  In your example, it should filter to an array of length one.  What result are you getting?

Comment: I replaced some with filter.it's returning myObject as the output,basically filtering is not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.some` just need at least one element in the array passes the test. So the filter method returned `true` and not filter anything.

Following ways could achieve your need.

```
var x = myObject.map(function (obj) {
    obj.treatmentList = obj.treatmentList.filter(function (item) {
        return item.procedureName == 'Bone Grafting' &&
            item.hospitalList.some(function (hospital) {
                return hospital.hospitalName == 'Renai';
            });
    });
    return obj;
});
```

Comment: According to OP's question, he also is filtering on the hospital name:  "For eg when the above json is filtered with procedure name 'Bone Grafting' & hospital name 'Renai' i should get the result in the below format."  So need to also add a check to verify the input hospital name exists in hospital list.

Comment: @dvsoukup Yes. I ignored it. Thank you for reminding. I corrected my answer just now.

Comment: Thanks.Fantastic solution

Answer (score 1):

## Observations

- You need to loop over your `myObject` array.
- Add a new call of `some` function for `hospitalList` array and compare with the `hospitalName`attribute.
- Finally add the found matches to your `treatmentList` array.

```js
var myObject = [{
  "department": "Gynic",
  "treatmentList": [{
      "procedureName": "Bone Grafting",
      "hospitalList": [{
          "hospitalName": "Renai",
        },
        {
          "hospitalName": "Aster",
        },
        {
          "hospitalName": "Appolo",
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "procedureName": "IVF",
      "hospitalList": [{
        "hospitalName": "Renai",
      }],
    }
  ]
}];

var myResultObject = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
  myResultObject.push({
    'department': myObject[i].department,
    'treatmentList': myObject[i].treatmentList.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.procedureName === 'Bone Grafting' && obj.hospitalList.some(function(hn) {
        return hn.hospitalName === 'Renai';
      });
    })
  });
}

console.log(myResultObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way or not but you ca try something like

```js
var myObject = [{
  "department": "Gynic",
  "treatmentList": [{
    "procedureName": "Bone Grafting",
    "hospitalList": [{
      "hospitalName": "Renai",
    }, {
      "hospitalName": "Aster",
    }, {
      "hospitalName": "Appolo",
    }],
  }, {
    "procedureName": "IVF",
    "hospitalList": [{
      "hospitalName": "Renai",
    }],
  }]
}];


function search(procedureName, hospitalName) {
  return myObject[0].treatmentList.filter(e => {
    if (e.procedureName === procedureName) {
      return e.hospitalList.filter(h => {
        return h.hospitalName === hospitalName
      })
    }
  })
}


console.log(search("IVF", "Renai"))
```